# Remote debuging JNI code on android from Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, java-native-interface

I have an Android application written in Java (Android studio) , which uses through JNI shared objects (*.o), compiled from c++ code using Toolchain on Eclipse.

The application running on Android mobile device connected through LAN to development computer (Windows PC) .
Cannot figured out how to debug remotely - through TCP/LAN connection in ECLIPSE, the C++ code.

Any guide/link /lead would be appreciated.

P.s : I managed to use the log ,but its not enough.

Comment: Eclipse is not a compiler, it's only an IDE. Same C++ code, with same NDK toolchain, you can compile from Android Studio. Then, you can use its built-in lldb. It's usually easier to connect to the Android system under debug with ADB and USB cable, but TCP over Wi-Fi works, with some limitations.

Comment: Alex Cohn, thanks for the lead. Trying to migrate my c++ code to android studio. My c++ code is organized in many projects (cproject) each project is build to a shared object,with inner dependency. Cannot figure out how to do the same thing in android studio .

Comment: Don't you have **Android.mk** files for each component?

Comment: I compile the projects using cross compiler with toolchain and internal builder. Maybe I missing something simple , but I cant figure out even how to organize my projects in android studio because it dont have a structure like project in eclipse ( its project is like workspace in eclipse)

Comment: I am sorry, I have never worked with NDK without Android.mk files with eclipse. As for converting eclipse projects to AS modules, you don't necessarily need them, AS does not support C++ modules anyway. You can add many C++ libraries to any AS application or library module.

Comment: Alex Cohn , thank you for the help. Meantime I managed to debug with LLDB (in AS), its a bit "stone age" debug but will do the work.